# How to connect asciidoc with source code in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, documentation, asciidoc

I manage my Spring Boot project with Gitlab. (git@gitlab.com:user/project.git).

I keep the documentation in the separate wiki project provided by Gitlab.  (so git@gitlab.com:user/project.wiki.git).

Now I want to refer directly from the documentation to the source code in the project and list code snippets for explanation. This way the code would always be up-to-date and you would only have to adapt the explanation if necessary. But how can I link from the wiki project to a remote file? To give an example, this is how it should look later on.

```
[source,java]
----
include:: https://gitlab.com/user/project/-/raw/master/src/main/java/de/mycompany/project/ProjectApp.java[]
----
```

Answer (score 2):

`asciidoctor` doesn't provide a way to perform remote includes: all include content has to be in the local filesystem.

If you use `asciidoctor.js`, you could use this extension: https://github.com/feelpp/asciidoctor-remote-include-processor

Otherwise, you could use some form of build coordination, such as make, Ant, etc. to fetch the remote content to a known local location, update your Asciidoc document(s) to include the now-local location, and then run `asciidoctor`.